# How to set parameters for browser when it starts

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I am developing a windows form application, it is for testing website application. It will set parameters (user agent, url address, DNS, ...) to browsers and then browser will start for testing.
Any idea! thanks!

I have tried:

I use Process.Start for start browser, but I can't set parameters that I need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the easiest way to change User Agent;

```
webBrowser1.Navigate ("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com", "_self" , null, "User-Agent: x");
```

[List of User-Agents web page has got many agents](http://www.user-agents.org/)

Comment: Thanks @Umut D. But use webBrowser1 when you use class WebBrowser, it default is Internet Explorer. I want implement on applications external and when start it we have setting parameters like Firefox, Chrome, IE...